# Error with prepared statement in node-odbc

Tags: odbc, vertica, node-odbc

I'm trying to run node-odbc against vertica and I'm getting a strange error when running a simple prepared statement.
The row is inserted in the db, but the program exits at `statement.execute()` with this error:

> $ node index.js
>   undefined:0
>
> Error: Invalid argument

```
const odbc = require('odbc');

async function executeExample() {
  const connection = await odbc.connect('Driver=/Library/Vertica/ODBC/lib/libverticaodbc.dylib;Servername=localhost;Port=5433;Database=testdb;UserName=dbadmin;Password=')
  const statement = await connection.createStatement();
  await statement.prepare('INSERT INTO testtable (name) VALUES(?)');
  await statement.bind(['joe']);
  const result = await statement.execute();
  console.log(result);
  await statement.close();
  await connection.close();
}

executeExample();
```